# Upgrading Tinn-R

Tags: r, installation, upgrade, tinn-r

I'm using Tinn-R version 2.2.0.2 and I want to upgrade to the latest version 2.3.4.4. I couldn't find any upgrade options in the menus of Tinn-R. So my question is: Is it safe to download and just install the new version? Will it overwrite my current Tinn-R settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can remember, the new version overwrites the existing one without a problem. In my case, however, the new version had many more problems in communicating with R console. For example it was very often the case that I was pressing the `R send: selection` button and nothing was happening.

I considered myself very lucky to have kept the Tinn-R 2.2.0.2 installer, and this is what I am using until now.

Comment: Thanks for this valuable info! The newest is not always the best. I'll keep on using the old one...

Comment: You could try the new one (you may be luckier than I), but be sure to keep the previous version's installer.

Comment: I would like to inform you that I have switched to Tinn-R 2.3.5.2 and haven't noticed any problems. The installation procedure does not overwrite current settings.

Answer (score 1):

With every new version Tinn-R tries to preserve (as much as possible) the user's preferences related to old version.

These preferences are stored in a temporary file (INI). This file is never removed when the program is uninstalled.

Farrel is correct:
In the user guide it Clearly states que Should one uninstall the prior Tinn-R and then install the new version!

In time, it was released two new versions this week (with many new features):

3.0.1.8: http://sourceforge.net/p/tinn-r/news/2013/11/tinn-r-3018-released/

3.0.1.9: http://sourceforge.net/p/tinn-r/news/2013/11/tinn-r-3019-released/

Answer (score 0):

I went through what you just did and switched because of it to notepad++ combined with NppToR.

Good luck,
Tal

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. 2.2.0.2 is cooperative at the moment. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am just a sheep who blindly follows but I stick to the instructions in the Tinn-R help file.
C:/Tinn-R/doc/english/user_guide/user_guide.html#basic_configuration_installconfigure
The easiest way to access the user guide is from the Tinn-R menu.
Help>Main>User guide>HTML

In the user guide it clearly states that one should uninstall the prior Tinn-R and then install the new version.